# Reading & writing disjoint sections of a memory mapped file from different threads under Windows

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

Is it safe to read and then write disjoint sections of a memory mapped file (mapped using Windows' `CreateFile`, `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile`) from multiple parallel threads running in the same process?

To me, it doesn't sound problematic because the different threads never read or write any common areas of the file.

Comment: Good question. But this sounds very problematic to me. For example, `cache lines`.